# Multiple Character Comment String Spark CSV Reader

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a tab delimited file that has comments denoted by `##`. I would like to read the file into a DataFrame, and want to use something like:

```
val targetDF = sparkSession.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("comment", "##")
  .load(pathToFile)
```

When I try this I get a runtime exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: comment cannot be more than one character`. Best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Then use just a single '#', each line starting with '#' will be considered as a comment. This is what the [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) says :

> comment (default empty string): sets the single character used for skipping lines beginning with this character. By default, it is disabled.

But be sure that no valid line starts with this character in your file.

```
val targetDF = sparkSession.read.format("csv")
 .option("header", "true")
 .option("inferSchema", "true")
 .option("delimiter", "\t")
 .option("comment", "#")
 .load(pathToFile)
```

Edit : because your records can contain a single '#' you'll have to omit the `comment` option and just filter manually your Dataframe afterwards or remove any line starting with two '#' in your file before parsing it.

Comment: Issue being the header starts with a single `#`, so it would be throwing away valid lines, and there is also no guarantee that my data doesn't start with `#`.

Comment: Can't you just prefix the header with something else ?

Comment: I am conforming to a file format [here](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf) and trying to expose the tool for other users. Also files are very large (~1.5 TB) so I would like to minimize IO

Comment: Edited my answer, in that case you'll have to filter your dataframe afterwards

Comment: My understanding of the file format is that the double hash only appears at the top of the file. I have though about loading the data into a Dataset[String] object and then parsing (would save the IO). Only problem with that approach is filtering over some ~3 billion records would be a waste if I know the lines to be removed are only at the top, is there perhaps a preempt-able filter that could stop after the pattern stops matching?

Comment: You're overthinking this. Just drop every line starting with '#' using the `comment` option or remove lines starting with '##' and you're good to go. Cheers